# add event listener for iframe in Sencha

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-architect

I am trying to add an event listener for iframe when it is loaded.

I put the following code in the init function for the controller.

```
init: function(application) {
var iframe = window.top.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
if(iframe) {
                Ext.EventManager.on(iframe.contentDocument.body, 'load', this.onload, this);
            }
//onload is my defined function.
```

However, the onload function has not been executed.

So I tried another code

```
var iframe = window.top.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
iframe.addEventListener("load", this.onBeforeUnload, false);
```

And the result is the same. Please tell a proper way to add an event listener for iframe when it is loaded in ExtJs.

UPDATED----

Thanks for the example. But when I tried to apply it to my real case, I encountered some difficulties. 
In my project, I have a home menu, pressing each menu button will do the following action:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('iframepanel"]')[0].update('<iframe src="buyitems">');
```

"/buyitems" page includes the controller I mentioned in the question. Now I am trying to listen for the iframe changes (e.g. beforeunload). If the iframe is changed, I would like to execute the function this.onBeforeUnload from controller to pop up a warning dialog for unsaved data.

I applied your code in my init function, but still cannot listen for the beforeunload event of iframe.

Comment: Has not your iframe already loaded by the time you attach listeners to it?

Comment: Yes, I used debugger to check, the iframe element can be retrieved successfully.

Comment: No, I mean what if the `load` event has already happened when you attach listener to it?

Comment: oh sorry I misunderstood, I also tried to listen for 'beforeunload' event, but still not succeed

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap your iframe in `Ext.dom.Element` and use [`on`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-method-on):

```
Ext.get(iframe).on('load', function() {
    console.log('LOADED!');
});
```

Example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/rt9